# PHP Download from webContentLink to server

Tags: php

I have mp3 files in my Google Drive that I want to download to my server.

Google Drive API gives me download urls like this:

> https://docs.google.com/uc?id=0B-8ZjfWGsMOwZVdmQnBXX1pnTEE&export=download

This code does not work:

```
$data = file_get_contents("https://docs.google.com/uc?id=0B-8ZjfWGsMOwZVdmQnBXX1pnTEE&export=download");
file_put_contents("./test.mp3", $data);
```

What do I have to change to get it working?

Comment: What is the result / error behaviour after the two lines which do not seem that wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the files are not accessable by a user that didn't login (error 403) to google.

It would be so simple using `file_get_contents` but unfortunately you have to authenticate to Google or change the permission of your mp3.

In a quick google search I found this blog explaining a class: http://hublog.hubmed.org/archives/001954.html

Keywords you could search for "google api auth php oauth class drive fetch files".

Answer (score 0):

Hello I was having the same issue, and the last answer it's not it, since getWebContentLink is supposed to be exactly for a downloadable link for unauthorized users, as said on the google developers website

*"If you want to allow an unauthorized user to download a file directly in a web browser instead of through the API, use the webContentLink. You can either redirect a user to this URL, or offer it as a clickable link."*

The problem with my code (and the above google statement) was that the files that I was uploading from my webapp were not shareable by default. In fact all files aren't.

so when I added to my code the proper permissions like this:

```
//the function
function insertGooglePermission($service, $fileId, $value, $type, $role) {
    set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . APP_ROOT . '/conf/google-drive/src');
    include_once APP_ROOT . '/conf/google-drive/vendor/autoload.php';

    $newPermission = new Google_Service_Drive_Permission();
    $newPermission->setValue($value);
    $newPermission->setType($type);
    $newPermission->setRole($role);
    try {
        return $service->permissions->insert($fileId, $newPermission);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        print "ERROR: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
    return NULL;
}

//and the usage
insertGooglePermission($service, $createdFile->getId(), "default", "anyone", "reader");
```

The 403 error went away. I must tell you that give this permission enables it to be, well accesible by ANYBODY who happens to know the file id, so I would think it can be risky ... for my needs it was perfect.

Hope it helps
Enjoy